# How to differentiate between a full node and an archive node while querying chain state?

Tags: storage, data-analytics

Is there a way to know whether the node you are querying is a full or an archive node? For example, assume you want to query the chain state at block 1000 for analytical purposes, to do this you need an archive node rather than a full node.

One differentiating characteristic I can see is [database size](https://paranodes.io/DBSize). But I am unsure of a practical way to do this when writing code to query the chain state at a particular block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a specific RPC that exposes this config information as to RPC pruning state.